# Where does the destroy action go for a has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a destroy action that deletes the association in the independent resource. Where does this action go? In the independent resource's controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < AR:Base
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :girls, :through => :friendship
end
```

create new controller:

```
rails g controller frienships
```

routes.rb

```
resource :friendship, :only => [:destroy]
```

friendships_controller

```
def destroy
  @friendsip = Friendship.find params[:id]
  @friendship.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

In show:

```
<%= link_to "Delete friendship", @your_user_friendship, :method => :delete %>
```

**BUT**

In my opinion you should implement it in your EDIT forms (in Users form and Girls) where you check and uncheck Girsl for User and vise versa. So it will automatically add and destroy friendship associations.

That way I usually do.

Comment: no I'm talking about a has_many, through association, not a has_many belongs_to association.

Comment: yeah but I'm talking about destroying the association in the friendship table, while keeping user and girls

Comment: i don't think that solves it... I want to be able to destroy an individual association from @user.girls... shouldn't there be a destroy action in the friendships controller?

Comment: oh I got it. For being REST you should create separate FRIENDSHIP resource. Or you can add destroy_friendship action to any of your resources: Girl or User.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm talking about. could you please provide an example?

Comment: what would go where `@your_user_friendship` is? `@friendship`?

Comment: Because if I put @friendship there, both the friendship and the user is deleted... I only want the friendship to be deleted

Comment: seems like a frienship model issue. let me see your model